# dropzone callback after multiple upload

Tags: events, dropzone.js

I'm using this code

```
<div id="dropzone">
    <form action="/adminUsers/upload" class="dropzone" id="myawesomedropzone">
        {{csrf_field()}}
    </form>
</div>

Dropzone.options.myawesomedropzone = {
    completemultiple : function(file, response){
        window.location='/admin/uploadSuccess';
    }
};

public function uploadImg()
{
    $file = request('file');
    $this->validate(request(),[
        'file'    =>    'required|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,bmp,png,gif'
    ]);
    $filename = time().mt_rand(1,9999).'.jpg';

    if( $file->move('uploads',$filename) ) {
        Admin::saveMedia($filename);
        return Response::json('success', 200);
    } else {
        return Response::json('error', 400);
    }
}
```

to create a drop zone and to redirect after multiple files are successfully uploaded. I used 'success' but its redirecting after the first file gets uploaded. I changed to 'completemultiple' but it doesn't redirect.

Answer (score 2):

solved the problem 'queuecomplete '

```
Dropzone.options.myawesomedropzone = {
    queuecomplete : function(file, response){
        window.location='/admin/uploadSuccess';
    }
};
```